# WCF STS load balancing and certificates

Tags: wcf, load-balancing, wif

Was wondering what the best practice for deploying a custom WCF - Security Token Service (STS) in a load balancing environment that uses signs and encrypts the token?

We're using Cirtix NetScaler to handle the load balancing and SSL termination (i.e. certificate is only installed on the NetScaler server). The STS has been specified to sign and encrypt the token via the SigningCertificateName and EncryptionCertificateName app settings. However the current web server configuration does not have a local certificate installed within it's certification store.

So my questions are:-

- Do we need to worry about signing and encrypting the token if it's transferred over SSL?
- Should we install the certificate on every web server or can we use the load balancer?
- Can we use the same certificate on each web server or do we need to buy a certificate for each web server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An STS which does not sign its tokens is not much use: without a signature, no relying party will be able to distinguish between a valid token issued by the STS and a token spoofed by someone with evil intent.

The certificate you install to support SSL is generally different to the STS's signing certificate. The latter identifies the Service, not the web server. So, by all means carry on installing the SSL certificate just on the load balancer. But you will need another certificate, representing the identity of the Service, installed (with its private key) on each machine which hosts the service, for use as the SigningCertificate. It should be the same certificate on each server (it's the same Service).

However, you typically don't need to **buy** such a certificate: you can issue your own - you just need to make sure each potential Relying Party is configured to recognise the certificate as a trusted STS, and also trusts the root issuer of the certificate (which will be either the certificate itself, if it is a self-signed certificate, or your root certificate, if you used a certificate server to issue it).

Comment: Thanks for answering the above questions.